# ApexSQL Complete or Redgate SQL Prompt?

Tags: ssms, redgate

I have been using Redgate SQL Prompt so far.  But I came to know about ApexSQL Complete which has the same features and is FREE!.

Has anyone used both the tools and has any idea if ApexSQL Complete offers all features of SQL Prompt and any reason to choose Redgate over ApexSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used both the tools and they are good. As mentioned earlier, [ApexSQL Complete](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-complete.aspx) has a free edition that has the necessary set of features for database developers.
You can also consider [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/editions.html) (there is a free edition) which also has many necessary features. The paid edition of [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/editions.html) has a good price and extended functionality comparing with other tools.
I recommend comparing [ApexSQL Complete](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-complete.aspx) and [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/editions.html).
From my point of view, the most important functions that should be in such tools:

- Code formatting
- Search for object definition
- Search for invalid objects
- Execution history
- Customizable tool settings and export/import of settings

Comment: Do you have a link to the free version of Apex Complete? I can only find the paid version on their website

Comment: ApexSQL went completely commercial. You won't find any more free products

Answer (score 4):

I have used ApexSQL for a few years now and I have also used various RedGate tools. Both are superb offerings, but I have a pretty big soft spot for ApexSQL... simply because they offer free SQL Tools. When I was starting out as a dev, ApexSQL offered me great tools without the price tag. I found them via this link way back when http://dirkstrauss.com/apexsql-tools-free/

When I started working as a contractor, being able to use some free tools kept my costs down. So ApexSQL definitely has a space to compete.

SQL Code Compare and SQL Search are my top go-to apps. In fact, the [SQL Search](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-search.aspx) has been indispensable when working on large databases that I was unfamiliar with.

If I had to choose between Redgate and ApesSQL, I wouldn't. I would use both as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable RedGate and install ApexSQL Complete to feel the difference yourself.

Try editing big queries with complex CTEs, views, stored procedures, change permissions on the objects, alter objects and so on.

It worth thousand of words.

Comment: Thanks, and yes that was my plan once my RedGate SQL Prompt trial version ends.